# background rollover on responsive image using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, rollover-effect

I am trying to have an overlay effect on a responsive image using CSS3 and bootstrap3. The problem is that the rollover brings an overlay background which applies on margins, so bigger than the image itself.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/prw-4.jpg">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#portfolio figure a:after {
    content:'Text';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
}
#portfolio figure a:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using box sizing since you are already using "experimental" css3
There is a good article here: [Box Sizing|CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

So basicly put:

```
* {
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;   /* Firefox 1, probably can drop this */
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   /* Safari 3-4, also probably droppable */
    box-sizing:        border-box;   /* Everything else */
}
```

In your css and that might perhaps solve it for you. 
Good luck.